# Is it correct to omit the indefinite article after the colon sign from the title of a scientific paper?

Tags: articles, indefinite-article, academic-writing

I am wondering if it is correct to replace,

**Learning English Language: A New Policy For Using Ell.stackexchange**

by

**Learning English Language: New Policy For Using Ell.stackexchange**

Comment: No, it has to stay.  But also: Learning English: A New X for Y. **or** Learning the English Language: A New X for Y. //scientific paper?? I wonder if you can call a policy paper a scientific paper...[Generally, we answer "it's fine to (whatever), but we don't use it to ask a question as in "is it fine to"]

Comment: @Lambie I'd keep the article but [_Disaster Hits Home: New Policy for Urban Housing Recovery_](https://www.ucpress.edu/book.php?isbn=9780520207806) by [Mary Comerio](https://ced.berkeley.edu/ced/faculty-staff/mary-comerio); [_New approach to the mixed-valence problem_](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.29.3035) by [Piers Coleman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piers_Coleman)

Comment: The Comero book does not have a colon. It is a two-line title. It has a title and a subtitle and therefore an article is not needed. Also here you could do the title like this: New Policy for Using X, but not without an A if it comes **after the colon**.

Comment: @Lambie I don't know if we see the same thing on [this page](https://www.google.com/search?q=Disaster+hits+home%3A+New+policy+for+urban+housing+recovery) or [this page](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Social_Welfare_and_Individual_Responsibi/YLxYP6UBW_EC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22is+it+fine+to%22&pg=PA93)

Comment: @EddieKal Her book does not contain colon. It is a title and sub-title **without a colon**. I'm done here. Too tiring to repeat myself over and over. Her actual book, not the booksellers' titles for her book. Look at **her book cover**. Hers, not theirs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Policy" can be either count or non-count.  Omitting "A" suggests the non-count meaning a category of principles, guidelines, plans and rules. Including "A" suggests the countable meaning "A document expressing policy, or a collection of principles etc. that are sufficiently aligned to be viewed as a singular thing.

> Policy should not be developed in a vacuum  (non-count)

> We have been developing policies to deal with cheating. (count)

In this case, it doesn't really matter much.  If this policy is expressed in the document then it is "A policy".

Comment: policy as non-count is not a collection of stuff. It is a category. Policy is something institutions have to deal with, for example.

Comment: @Lambie "The policy we have written here has always taken into account the interests of all affected parties."   "Policy" is not a collective signifier here??

Comment: yes, category is a better word